# jQuery count of values in object

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have an object returned as -

```
[[1234, 3], [3245, 14], [3421, 0], [1231, 40]]
```

I want to count as 3+14+0+40 using JQuery? I know underscore js has countBy in version 1.4. We don't have 1.4 installed. Is there a very short way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simle iterate,

```
var data = [[1234, 3], [3245, 14], [3421, 0], [1231, 40]];

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total += data[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you use underscore, you can use `_.reduce` function:

```
_.reduce(theArray, function(memo, ar) { return memo + ar[1]; } ,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's javascript task

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i=array.length; i--;) {
   sum += array[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not (admitting that your array is in the var tab)

```
var res = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    res += tab[i][tab[i].length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jQuery for this?  This is basic Javscript 101

```
var t = 0; // The total
var i;
for (i = 0;  i < a.length; i++) {
  t += a[i][1]
}
```